# iOS - Naming Convention for IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I did search around and I found a bunch of conventions but none talk about IBOutlets.

Which one of the following should I use?

```
@IBOutlet weak var price: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPrice: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tfPrice: UITextField!
```

Comment: 2nd and especially the 3rd sound and look very bad, if anything use the 1st or `priceTextField`, including the type *after* the actual meaning of the field.

Comment: True, forgot about that option. I just added it to the questions.

Comment: Also note that most modern naming conventions prefer not to include "type" in variable names. Personally, I would name the variable just `priceField`. If you then change the type to `UISearchField` or other class, you won't have to rename it.

Answer (score 6):

This is the naming convention for IBOutlets that I often see the most in the developer's code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
```

Comment: What about when you have 5 UITextFields and you forgot how you named that 4th text field, wouldn't it be easy to name those text fields textFieldUsername, now if you forgot the name you can always start with textField and wait for auto completion from Xcode.

Comment: @Oh If you forgot the name, or the name is difficult to come up if you know the exact usage, that mean, the naming of that text field maybe in a problem.  The naming convention of an item should always clearly defined across team.